# Database design for storing multiple address and contact number of a employee

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, rdbms

Suppose a scenarios of Employee Database.

I have to store all the details of employee like empid, name, designation, address, contact number, emailid.

If a employee have multiple address and multiple contact number than how to design a database.

please give a brief details of designing the same.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you come up with so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: I would like to know that how to design, whether address and contact will be a new entity or we can use it in same.

Comment: do youu have concepts of relationship of tables in database

Comment: @AsadJatoi i am a beginner in database

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(20),
  `designation` VARCHAR(20),
  `email` VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`emp_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `adress` (
  `addr_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` BIGINT,
  `detail` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`addr_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `contact_number` (
  `ct_num_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` BIGINT,
  `number` VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ct_num_id`)
);


ALTER TABLE `adress` ADD CONSTRAINT `adress_fk1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES employee(`emp_id`);

ALTER TABLE `contact_number` ADD CONSTRAINT `contact_number_fk1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES employee(`emp_id`);
```

You can use table design like this. In the source code you have to manage which adresses and contact numbers belongs to employee.